# CGI error using wkhtmltopdf in Azure web app

Tags: c#, azure, azure-web-app-service, wkhtmltopdf

In my ASP.Net Core web app I'm using DinkToPdf, a C# wrapper for the wkhtmltopdf library.

My app is deployed as an Azure web service (standard plan).

Locally, I can generate pdfs without any issues. But for a few days now, I'm getting the following error on Azure while trying to generate a pdf:

> The specified CGI application encountered an error and the server terminated the process.

The wkhtmltopdf library is not yet fully supported by Azure (https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Azure-Web-App-sandbox#unsupported-frameworks) - but anyways, it has been working for weeks.

I didn't made any minor changes to my project.
Maybe someone has an idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the issue:
an url used in the html template was wrong (pointed to localhost) and led to the CGI error.

Comment: I ran into the same issue. Removing a localhost reference in my html fixed it

Comment: I got the same problem and I resolve with your solution Felix, thank you so much.